# iPhone SDK: How can you hide an alert box?

Tags: iphone

I am using the following code to show an alert box:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"My Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];  
[alert show];  
[alert release];
```

Can you tell me how to hide the alert box again when the phone changes orientation?

Comment: Refer to the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for help formatting your question. Most importantly, you should put four spaces before your code, so it gets formatted like code (or you can select it and press the `{}` button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to save a reference to the alert in your interface.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UIAlertView *alert;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;
```

when you create the alert you use

```
self.alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"My Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];  
[alert show];
```

and then you have to add another method `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[alert cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
    self.alert = nil;
}
```